# Mixing Wordpress Functions with Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a modified an existing Wordpress plugin. Now I wanna refactor that code into an own plugin. So the owner of the page is able to update the original Plugin without destroying / overwriting my changes. The code is a quite simple Javascript snippet, which places a `get_metadata` value into a textfield.

I am totally new on Wordpress Plugins.

What are the most basic needs to get that code loaded **with** the Userdata. (For example in the bottom scripts?)

```
$form_html .= '<script> 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    function assign_bandname() {
        var $bandname = "' . get_metadata("user", get_current_user_id(), "band_name", true) . '";
        var $container = jQuery(".plugins_class_container").first();
        var $bandscope = $container.find(\'input[type=text],select\').filter(\':visible:first\');
        $bandscope.val($bandname);
    }

    assign_bandname();

    jQuery("button").unbind().click(function() {
        setTimeout(assign_bandname, 800);
    })
});
</script>';
```

I found some Skeletons for wordpress Plugins, but they are loaded with a lot of admin, I18n, and function stuff. I am completely overwhelmed with that, and did not find an "easy" solution. But I think there would be one... :-)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is at times necessary to do this in your theme. For this WordPress has provided us with `wp_localize_script` function. The benefit of using this function is that you don't have to enqueue anything in the `header.php`.

Add this to your functions file:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_js_library', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/myLibrary.js' );

$dataToBePassed = array(
     'bandname'            => get_current_user_id(),
);
wp_localize_script( 'my_js_library', 'php_vars', $datatoBePassed );
```

You can use the value of `wp_localize_script` function in the my_js_library.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand a bit on Jayman's answer, the bare minimum you need for the plugin itself is the folder name of your plugin with and `index.php` something like the below example. You will also want to add a script.js file in that folder that will contain the js you want to add. Just need to add that folder in `wp-content->plugins` and activate the plugin.

[Here is a good link talking about the 'Wordpress Way' of passing data to Javascript](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-pass-php-data-and-strings-to-javascript-in-wordpress--wp-34699).

```
/*
    Plugin Name: My Plugin
    Plugin URI: http://allyourbase.com
    Description: my first plugin
    Version: 1.0
    Author: someone
    Author URI: http://something.com
*/

    /**
     * initiate the plugin 
     * @return void
     */
    function init(){
        add_scripts();
    }

    /**
     * add plugin scripts
     */
    function add_scripts(){

        wp_enqueue_script( 'script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/script.js', false, '', true );

        wp_localize_script('thatgooddata', 'userdata', wp_get_current_user());
    }

    init();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by creating a `template-name-child` folder.

placed there the following files:

- style.css
- screenshot.jpg
- functions.php
- script.js
- readme.txt

the most important part is functions.php:

```
<?php

// template
//add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles');

wp_enqueue_scripts('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles');

function theme_enqueue_styles()
{
    // template-name == parent-template-name
    wp_enqueue_style('template-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('bootstrap', 'jquery', 'font-awesome'));
}

// custom scripts
function theme_enqueue_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('frontend-ajax', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_localize_script('frontend-ajax', 'custom_vars',
        array(
            'bandname' => get_metadata("user", get_current_user_id(), "band_name", true),
        )
    );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts');
?>
```

Now I am able to call from my `script.js` the variables by

```
console.log(my_vars.bandname);
```

The readme.txt contains

```
=== Template Name Child ===
Author: Your Name
Tags: black, blue, white, light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, fixed-layout, responsive-layout, custom-background, custom-header, custom-menu, editor-style, featured-images, microformats, post-formats, rtl-language-support, sticky-post, theme-options, threaded-comments, translation-ready
Requires at least: 4.0
Tested up to: 4.4.1
Stable tag: 1.0
License: GNU General Public License v3 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html

== Description ==
Modern & beautiful responsive theme.
```

The style.css contains:

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Template Name Child
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-fifteen-child/
 Description:  Template Name Child Theme
 Author:       Your Name
 Author URI:   https://www.yourUrl.com
 Template:     template-name
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         dark
 Text Domain:  template-name-child
*/
```